# Flutter gradient background for entire screens issue

Tags: flutter, background, gradient, builder

I was trying to add gradient background to all screens at once so I found a good way but it's not working as expected !!

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Container(
      decoration: const BoxDecoration(
        gradient: LinearGradient(
          colors: [
            Colors.red,
            Colors.white,
          ],
          begin: Alignment.topLeft,
          end: Alignment.bottomRight,
        ),
      ),
      child: MaterialApp(
        builder: EasyLoading.init(),
        home: Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

after checking the code I found that if I removed `builder: EasyLoading.init(),` it work fine !!
But I want the EasyLoading .. so is there a way for it ?

Comment: The issue is not with getx 'GetMaterialApp', I removed it for you ^_^ still the same.

Answer (score 0):

Please try using the `Stack` widget to overlay the gradient background and EasyLoading on top of each other.

```
Stack(
      children: [
        Container(
          decoration: const BoxDecoration(
            gradient: LinearGradient(
              colors: [
                Colors.red,
                Colors.white,
              ],
              begin: Alignment.topLeft,
              end: Alignment.bottomRight,
            ),
          ),
        ),
        MaterialApp(
          builder: (context, child) {
            return Stack(
              children: [child!, EasyLoading.init()],
            );
          },
          home: Scaffold(
            backgroundColor: Colors.transparent,
          ),
        ),
      ],
    )
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Sorry, it didn't work..